# Adding an existing SQL Server 2008 database to plesk

Tags: sql-server-2008, plesk

[image: my plesk panel]

This is what my plesk panel looks like. There is a databases item under applications & services. when I click it, it allows me to add a new database but I cannot figure out how to add an existing database (SQL Server 2008) to it. I googled it **a lot** and the most common reply was to just simply run the database's script! *Where to run the script*, is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is a bit tricky because `phpmyadmin` has direct import. But there is some good out there with which we .Net developers can live with.

you can do following steps.

1. Run your sql server configuration manager and configure your `TCiP`=> enabled and restart sql service
2. Login to `Plesk` create database and add user to it.
3. Create ODBC SQL connection there.
4. Replace `(local)` with the your website `DNS(ip)` and manage rest of settings. Note that you have to provide username and password here that you added for db user
5. Test the connection if it is a success then you are almost done
6. In your SQL server Management Studio you connect using above credentials (server add,username and Pass)
7. If successful you would be connected and see the database you created there.
8. You can right click database and GOTO `Tasks`->`Import and Export` from that wizard you need to select the appropriate source and then wizard will guide you all the way.

there you go......

Happy Programming :)